# Cocycle condition for 2-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, cohomology, group-cohomology

I know that if $\omega_d(g_1, \ldots, g_d)$ is an d-cocycle characterized by $H^d(G,U(1))$, it satisfies the co-cycle condition 
$(d\omega_d)(g_1, \ldots, g_{d+1}) = g_1.\omega_d(g_2,\ldots,g_{d+1}) + \sum_{i=1}^d (-1)^i \omega_d(g_1, \ldots, g_{i-1}, g_i g_{i+1}, g_{i+2}, \ldots, g_{d+1}) + (-1)^{d+1} \omega_d(g_1, \ldots,g_d) = 0$.

In the paper *[Higher symmetry and gapped phases of gauge theories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4721)* (by Kapustin and Thorngren) the authors mention the cohomology of 2-groups, $H^d(\mathbb{G},U(1))$. $\mathbb{G} = \{\Pi_1,\Pi_2,\alpha,\beta\}$ where $\Pi_1$ is any finite group, $\Pi_2$ is a finite Abelian group, $\alpha:\Pi_1 \rightarrow Aut(\Pi_2)$ and $\beta \in H^3(\Pi_1,\Pi_2)$. Is there an equivalent of the co-cycle condition for any $d$? The authors mention the explicit result for $d=2$ in page 18 but not a general form.

PS: I am a physicist so I apologize for any mistakes in the way I have phrased my question.

Comment: I added the title and authors to your opaque arXiv link. Yes there is such a equivalent, namely but it's usually expressed in a more abstract way, namely as a higher functor from the delooping of $\mathbb{G}$ (i.e. the one-object 2-groupoid built from the data you give) to the $d$-times delooped $U(1)$ -- this is a $d$-groupoid (i.e. in the pattern groupoid, 2-groupoid, 3-groupoid,..) with a single object, a single 1-arrow, a single 2-arrow,...., a single $(d-1)$-arrow and then $U(1)$-worth of $d$-arrows.

Comment: Alternatively, one could use a simplicial model, then you would be looking at data that encodes a map of simplicial sets from the reduced (i.e. only one 0-simplex) simplicial set classified by the data for $\mathbb{G}$, to a simplicial model for a $K(U(1),d)$. Hope this helps. I can perhaps track down papers that give more details given a bit more time.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, thank you for improving the question and your comments. I would really appreciate it if you can share a reference that gives details of the simiplicial model. Any other helpful references is also highly appreciated.